# Understanding the answers of $x^2 \equiv 28 \pmod 6$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

> Solving  $x^2 \equiv 28 \pmod 6$

The answers are: $x \equiv 2 \pmod 6$ and $x \equiv 4 \pmod 6$.

When I plugged in to check the answers, it would be $2^2 \equiv 4 \pmod 6$ and $4^2 \equiv 16 \equiv 4 \pmod 6$. It is $4$ but not $28$, why is this, I don't understand? Anyone can help me understand this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $4\equiv28\pmod6$

Comment: Your title and question do not match, although they are equivalent.

Comment: So, instead of solving $x^2 \equiv 28 \pmod 6$, I can solve $x^2 \equiv 4 \pmod 6$. Am I right about this?

Comment: Yes, if $x^2\equiv4$ and $4\equiv28$, then $x^2\equiv28\pmod6$

Comment: Wow, all these congruence are so complicated...

Comment: Thanks a lot! ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Congruence is an equivalence relation, so transitive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $4\equiv28\pmod6$,

$x^2\equiv4\pmod 6\iff x^2\equiv28\pmod6$.

Comment: I got another question is that: Can I solve $x \equiv 4 \pmod 6$ instead of $x \equiv 28 \pmod 6$? Does it applied for non-square number?

Comment: Since $4\equiv28\pmod6$, $x\equiv4\pmod6\iff x\equiv28\pmod6$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

We start with $x^2\equiv28\bmod6$.  As far as simply checking the two given answers, firstly replace $x$ by $2$ to get the true statement $2^2\equiv28\bmod6$ (since $2^2=4$ and $6|(28-4)=24$).

Similarly, replacing $x$ with $4$ gives us a true statement:  $4^2\equiv28\bmod6\iff0\equiv12\bmod6$.